# How to change comment character from # (hash) to % (percent sign) for Octave major mode

Tags: major-mode, comment, syntax-table

By default, `comment-region` inserts `#` for comments in Octave major mode:

```
# foo
```

I want to modify the behavior so that it inserts the percent sign

```
% foo
```

I used the following

```
(setq octave-mode-hook
      (lambda () (setq octave-comment-char ?%) ))
(modify-syntax-entry ?% "<"  octave-mode-syntax-table)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: octave-mode-syntax-table
```

I don't know about elisp so well, so how can I solve this?

**Edit**

Here is the configuration needed to make `octave-mode` the default one for `.m` files and change commenting behaviour to that of MATLAB's. Note that for Octave, both `%` and `#` are valid for commenting.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m\\'" . octave-mode))

(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
    (lambda () (progn (setq octave-comment-char ?%)
                      (setq comment-start "% ")
                      (setq comment-add 0))))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside your hook put this: `(setq comment-start "% ")`. Also, this will explain why:

> comment-region is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
>
> `(comment-region BEG END &optional ARG)`
>
> Comment or uncomment each line in the region. With just C-u prefix
>   arg, uncomment each line in region BEG .. END. Numeric prefix ARG
>   means use ARG comment characters. If ARG is negative, delete that many
>   comment characters instead.
>
> The strings used as comment starts are built from `comment-start` and
>   `comment-padding`; the strings used as comment ends are built from
>   `comment-end` and `comment-padding`.
>
> By default, the `comment-start` markers are inserted at the current
>   indentation of the region, and comments are terminated on each line
>   (even for syntaxes in which newline does not end the comment and blank
>   lines do not get comments).  This can be changed with `comment-style`.

Comment: This worked for me. Can you also help me with that `syntax-table` error? I want to change the commenting behavior so that it inserts only one percent sign instead of two.

Comment: @hos You don't need to make that modification to Octave mode's syntax table. Percents are already recognized as being the comment start symbol. The reason you were getting an error is perhaps because Octave mode wasn't loaded yet when that code ran. If you want a single character to begin a comment, you can similarly add `(setq comment-add 0)` to the hook.

Answer (score 3):

The `octave-comment-char` was added specifically for your kind of use case, so all you should need is:

```
(setq octave-comment-char ?%)
```

No need to change the syntax table, since `%` is already recognized as a comment starter.  The important detail is that the above `setq` needs to be executed before `octave.el` is loaded (so its values is correctly propagated to other vars such as `comment-start`).

Comment: Was this added recently?

Comment: Sorry I was confused, I was thinking about something else